# perl: The ways of determining the size of an array of strings don't seem to work

Tags: perl

Just started learning perl about three days ago.

I have an array of strings that I load from a text file thus:

```
my @fileContents;
my $fileDb = 'junk.txt';
open(my $fmdb, '<', $fileDb);
push @fileContents, [ <$fmdb> ];
```

The file is known to be 1205 lines long but I can not retrieve the size of the array, i.e. a count of the number of lines loaded into the array.

I tried three different ways described here and elsewhere about how to determine the number of elements in an array of strings, and can not seem to get any of them to work.

Following is my code, commented to include the three different ways I found in my research, to find the number of elements in an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Load the contents of a text file into an array, one line per array element.

# Standard header stuff.
# Require perl 5.10.1 or later, and check for some typos and program errors.
#
use v5.10.1;
use warnings;
use strict;

# Declare an array of strings to hold the contents of the files.
#
my @fileContents;

# Declare and open the file.
#
my $fileDb = 'junk.txt';  # a 1205-line text file

open(my $fmdb, '<', $fileDb) or die "cannot open input file $!";

# Get the size of the array before loading it from the file.
# That size should be zero and is correctly reported as such.
#
my $sizeBeforeLoading = @fileContents;
say "size of fileContents before loading is $sizeBeforeLoading.";

# Load the file into the array then close the file.
#
push @fileContents, [ <$fmdb> ];

close( $fmdb );

# Now the array size should be 1205 but I can't get it to report that.
# Tried it three different ways.

my $sizeAfterLoading = @fileContents;
say "size of fileContents after loading is $sizeAfterLoading.";
#
# That didn't work; it reports a size of 1 when the real size is known to be 1205.
#
# Tried this:

$sizeAfterLoading = scalar @fileContents;
say "size of fileContents after loading is $sizeAfterLoading.";
#
# This one reported a size of 1.

$sizeAfterLoading = $#fileContents + 1;
say "size of fileContents after loading is $sizeAfterLoading.";
#
# This one reported an index of 0 for a size of 1.

# The real size is known to be 1205 so hard-code one less than that here
#
$sizeAfterLoading = 1204;

say "The file contents are:";

foreach my $i( 0..$sizeAfterLoading )
{
  print $fileContents[ 0 ][ $i ];
}
#
# The contents of the fileContents array prints out correctly (all 1205 lines of text).
```

Printing out the contents of the array and matching it with the input file verifies that the array is getting loaded correctly (even redirected the output to a file and used diff to compare with the input file and they matched), but I still can't get the array size (number of lines of text).

My guess is that having to access $fileContents as a two-dimensional array has something to do with it.  I initially expected to just be able to say "print $fileContents[$i];" but that didn't work; I needed to insert the [0] in there ahead of the [$i].  I really don't understand why that is.

Can someone help me understand why the size-of-array doesn't work, and how to do it the right way in this context?

Comment: The "size of array" is working just fine; it's correctly telling you that you've created an array of one element. That's not what you *meant* to do, but it's what you did.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be loading the entire file into an array reference, and storing the array reference in an array, then you check the size of the *array*, and of course it is 1.

```
push @fileContents, [ <$fmdb> ];
#                   ^---------^--- creates array ref
```

What you want is:

```
push @fileContents, <$fmdb>;
```

Or why not

```
@fileContents = <$fmdb>;
```

If you do have a multi-dimensional array, and you want to check the size of one of the inner arrays, what you do is to first dereference it properly:

```
my $size = @{ $fileContents[0] };  # check size of first array
```

To be clear, what you have done is this:

```
my @file = <$fmdb>;        # store file in array
my @fileContent = \@file;  # store array in other array
my $size = @fileContent;   # = 1 only contains one element: a reference to @file
```

Comment: OK, good.  The problem was putting the entire file into an array reference with [].  Take those away and all is right with the world.  I have a lot to learn about this perl stuff... :-)  Thanks!